# Discover if another record is being inserted right now by another transaction in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Imagine there is an open, ongoing transaction in Postgresql inserting a record and doing something else as well.

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO films(id, name) VALUES(10, 'A comedy')
  # We are at this moment in time
  # The transaction is not yet committed
  # ...
COMMIT
```

Is there any non-blocking way to discover from outside of this transaction that there is an ongoing transaction inserting record with ID=10 right now?

The only way I could think about was:

```
BEGIN
SET statement_timeout to 100
INSERT INTO films(id, name) VALUES(10, '') ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING
ROLLBACK
```

- if I get a timeout from INSERT than it means that there is another ongoing transaction
- if I inserted nothing then there was a transaction which is now finished and conflict on unique ID occured
- if the INSERT succeeded and thenI rolled-back than it means there is no transaction right now trying to insert a row with ID=10

However this is less than ideal as:

- It is not non-blocking, I am waiting 100ms here
- I am doing an INSERT operation, whereas I would prefer a read-only solution
- As far as I understand I am actively triggering a conflict but I cannot in any easy way enforce that the 2nd transaction gets deadlock and that I won't ever interrupt the work of the 1st transaction

I am effectively trying to workaround the lack of READ UNCOMMITTED transaction isolation level in Postgresql.

I am in charge of both parts of the code so I can change them in any way necessary to allow it.